# create new pandas column based on matching values from previous records

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, for-loop

I have a pandas dataframe with columns name and id, like the input data below.  I would like to create a new column "label" such that if the record with the id one less than the current record has the same name value then the current record would have the same alphabetic value in the label column as the previous record.  If it has a different value in name then I would like to increment to the next alphabetic value.  I've provided example output data below to illustrate what I'm trying to do.  Does anyone know of a slick way to do this with pandas or otherwise?

input data:

```
name id
cat   0
cat   1
dog   2
frog  3
```

output data:

```
label name id
A     cat   0
A     cat   1
B     dog   2
C     frog  3
```

Comment: Are you ever going to go past Z ?

Answer (score 0):

here is one way:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase
from itertools import count



gen_letter = ((c * i for c in ascii_uppercase) for i in count(1))
r = []
for i, t in df.name.eq(df.name.shift()).items():
    if t:
        r.append(r[i - 1])
    else:
        r.append(next(gen_letter))

df['label'] = r
```

[image]

this solution is for many labels after you finish the alphabet will go like: 'AA', 'BB' ....

Comment: thank you for getting back to me so quickly with this.  When I try to run it I'm getting a "data_df2['label'] = r

StopIteration: "  error, do you kno what might be causing that?

Comment: @user3476463 I just show for your example, if you have many names in your column you can check now my code

Comment: when I run your new code I'm getting "<generator object <genexpr>.<genexpr> at 0x7fb.." for all the label values.  Is there something I'm missing?  I'm on python 3.6

Comment: @user3476463 weird, I have pyton 3.7